# Malloc Memory corruption in C

Tags: c, malloc, cuda, gpu

I have a problem using malloc.

I have a function called `jacobi_gpu` wich is called many times :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    /* ... */

    int totalrot=0;
    while(nrot>0){
        iter++;
        nrot=jacobi_gpu(a,q, tol, dimmat);
        totalrot+=nrot;

        printf("iter =%3d  nrot=%3d\n",iter, nrot);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

The parameters a,q,tol and dimmat are correctly initialized. 
A and Q are 2 square matrices and dimmat is their dimension.

Here is my code :

```
int jacobi_gpu(double A[], double Q[], double tol, long int dim){
    int nrot, p, q, k, tid;
    double c, s;
    double *mc, *vc;

    printf("jacobi begins \n");

    mc   = (double *)malloc(2 * dim * sizeof(double));
    vc   = (double *)malloc(2 * dim * sizeof(double));

    if( mc == NULL || vc == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "pb allocation matricre\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    nrot = 0;

    for(k = 0; k < dim - 1; k++){
        eye(mc, dim);
        eye(vc, dim);

        for(tid = 0; tid < floor(dim /2); tid++){
            p = (tid + k)%(dim - 1);
            if(tid != 0)
                q = (dim - tid + k - 1)%(dim - 1);
            else
                q = dim - 1;

            //printf("p = %d | q = %d\n", p, q);
            if(fabs(A[p + q*dim]) > tol){

                nrot++;
                symschur2(A, dim, p, q, &c, &s);

                mc[2*tid] = p;        vc[2 * tid] = c;
                mc[2*tid + 1] = q;    vc[2*tid + 1] = -s;

                mc[2*tid + 2*(dim - 2*tid) - 2] = p;
                vc[2*tid + 2*(dim - 2*tid)   - 2 ] = s;

                mc[2*tid + 2*(dim - 2*tid) - 1] = q;
                vc[2 * tid + 2*(dim - 2*tid) - 1 ] = c;     
            }
        }

        affiche(mc,dim,2,"Matrice creuse");
        affiche(vc,dim,2,"Valeur creuse");

    }
    printf("end\n");
    free(mc);
    free(vc);
    return nrot;
}
```

My problem is in the malloc call on the mc variable :

```
*** glibc detected *** ./jacobi_gpu: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000022944a0 ***
    *** glibc detected *** ./jacobi_gpu: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000002294580 ***
```

Any advice?

[EDIT]

- The function **eye** initializes an identity matrix
- The function **affiche** displays the matrix with lines and columns. The first parameter is the matrix, the second is the number of lines and the third one is the number of column.

### More explanation

The purpose of the matrix mc is to store the variables p and q. Those variables contains column indices. 
The purpose of the matrix vc is to store the values contained in those column. 
For instance, if the first line of the matrix mc is 0 and 5 ( p = 0, q = 5), that means that the values in the matrix vc will be in the column 0 and 5.
  If the matrix fifth line in the matrix mc is 2 3 ( p = 2, q = 3), that means that the values in the fifth line in vc will be in column 2 and 3.

Hope this time, i am more clear.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What happens when you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: What does `eye()` do, and when does the failure happen? i.e. does it happen on the first call to `malloc()` or after several calls?

Comment: For that matter, what does `affiche()` do?

Comment: @james `affiche()` translates to poster, so I'm guessing an output wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identity matrices are always square, but mc is not. When you call `eye(mc, dim)` I suspect that eye treats mc like it is a dim by dim matrix when it is in fact a 2 by dim matrix, and writes to unallocated memory.

Comment: Ah, the `eye()` s have it `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You are not allocating enough memory for a square matrix in your call to `malloc()`. The correct size would be `dim` squared, not just `2*dim`.

This should do the trick:

```
mc   = (double *)malloc(dim * dim * sizeof(double));
vc   = (double *)malloc(dim * dim * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: ... so the matrix operations probably overwrite the `malloc` bookkeeping info.

Comment: Nope, this is the correct dimension of my matrix. This matrix contains 2 columns and N lines. The purposes of this matrix is to store the values p and q.

Comment: @larsmans: That makes sense. Of course, once you start writing to un-allocated memory, there are no guarantees.

Comment: @Dimitri: Hmm, then it's back to square one.

Comment: @e.james Where exactly is he writing to un-allocated memory? All of his array indexing expressions end up being between 0 and 2*dim.

Comment: @Dimitri: You said your matrices were square in the question.

Comment: @Null Set: True story. The mention of square matrices in the question threw me off.

Comment: @nmichaels: The matrices A and Q are square matrices.But the matrix mc and vc are not squared.

Comment: @Dimitri: Ah, that makes more sense. I missed how different they were.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the `double free or corruption (!prev)` is that you're calling free() multiple times on the same pointer, your other functions might be doing this (I suspect `affiche()`.
Maybe try running it after `export MALLOC_CHECK_=0` on your shell?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a stack corruption somewhere in your code. Compile with debug options and run your code through valgrind, it will tell you.

BTW, in C casting the result of `malloc` is a bad idea. Don't do that, it might hide the diagnostic of the lack of including the correct header file.